# Credit Card Expiry Check Linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My application automatically bills subscribed customers using a payment processing vendor. I keep only information on the expiry date of the card and the vendors reference number for auto-billing.  Everyday I want to check  members whose cards will expire within 30 days.  I am running a background process to send email reminders. I am struggling getting Linq to accept my query.  The expiry date is stored in the database as a string eg 0319 for March 2019.  I am wondering if I have any chance of getting this to work. Please assist if you can. My last resort might be having  to format expiry dates currently stored as strings mmyy in database to proper dates.

```
int mon = DateTime.Now.Month;
int yr = DateTime.Now.Year;
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(yr, mon);
int dy = DateTime.Now.Day;
var allCardExpiring = db.DirectDebits.Include(i => i.Customer).Where(a =>a.DdOk && a.Customer.PassOk &&  DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(a.DateExpiry.Substring(2, 4)), Convert.ToInt32(a.DateExpiry.Substring(0, 2)))+days-dy < 30).Select(a => a.DirectDebitId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Why not precalculate the next month to expire, and select all cards with that date?

Comment: Not sure if this is really a good idea. I mean storing sensitive information like credit card numbers etc should be done only with the uttermost security measures. Are you following the [PCI DSS standards](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/)?

Comment: Steve I am not storing credit card numbers only expiry dates customers have subscribed for automatic billing and  some need to be reminded of their expiry

Comment: @Steve I have made what I store clear now

Comment: `a.DateExpiry == bob;` will be the LINQ condition. Before the LINQ `var bob = DateTime.Today.ToString("DDMM");`

Comment: I have found a workaround this thanks @mjwills

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example that shows that you should not form the database into the format that operators use to enter their input. If your database would have had the `ExpiryDate` as a DateTime, you wouldn't have had this problem. Of course with the cost that when operators enter their expiry date you would have to convert it to a DateTime, but (1) that is easier than converting back and (2) What do you  more often: query the ExpiryDate or update it?

If you are stuck with this database, then my advice would be to create a query where you split your `MonthYear` property into a a `Month` and a `Year`, using [DbFunctions.Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.left?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) and [DbFunctions.Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.right?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) then convert it in your query to a proper DateTime using [DbFunctions.CreateDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.createdatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

If you need this conversion for other functions, consider creating separate IQueryable functions for this, so you can re-use it.

As extension function for your DirectDebit that takes an input sequence of DirectDebits and returns a DateTimeDirectDebit sequence:

```
public static IQueryable<DateTimeDirectDebit> ToDateTimeDirectDebits(
    this IQueryable<DirectDebit> directDebits)
{
    return directDebits.Select(directDebit => new
    {
        // split ExpiryDate into a Month and a Year
        ExpiryDate = new
        {
            Month = DbFunctions.Left(directDebit.DateExpire, 2),
            Year = DbFunctions.Right(directDebit.DateExpire, 2),
        }
        DirectDebit = directDebit,
    })
    .Select(directDebit => new DateTimeDirectDebit
    {
         // create the ExpiryDate as DateTime
         ExpiryDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(
            directDebit.ExpiryDate.Year,
            directDebit.ExpiryDate.Mnth,
            1,                                // first day of the month
            ...),
         DirectDebit = directDebit.DirectDebit,
    });
}
```

You also need a function that returns the DateTimeDirectDebits that expire within a certain amount of days. Again as an extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<DateTimeDirectDebit> WhereExpiresWithinDays(
   this IQueryable<DateTimeDirectDebit> source,
   int nrOfDays)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.now;
    DateTime limitDate = now.AddDays(nrOfDays);
    return source.Where(directDebit => directDebit.ExpiryDate < limitDate);
}
```

Similarly you might want a function that returns all directDebits that expire next Month use DbFunctions.DiffMonths for this.

Usage:

```
using (var dbContext = new ...)
{
    var directDebitsThatExpireNextMonth = dbContext.DirectDebits
        .ToDateTimeDirectDebits
        .WhereExpiresWithinDays(30)
        .Select(...);
}
```

The nice thing is, that by using these LINQ-like extension methods, you can hide how your database is structured, especially the parts that you are not happy about. This way, your code does not have to be restructures so much if your database changes internally, especially those functions that don't use these changes.

Of course, for a proper hiding of the database structure, class DateTimeDirectDebits should not expose property DirectDebits, but only the properties you want to show to the outside world.

Comment: I would actually argue that storing an Expiry Date as `datetime` **isn't** a great solution. Why? Well, what date would you store for `0319`? If you leave it as `0319` then the meaning is clear - people understand how expiry dates work for credit cards (i.e. this card will expire at the end of March 2019). But if you want a `datetime`, what do you use? 1st of March? 1st of April? Last possible millisecond of March? I've worked on systems that used `datetime` columns like that, and honestly they sucked a bit. I wish they'd just stored `0319`.

Comment: The fact that the card expires at the end of the month is arbitrary. It is just policy of the credit card company concerned. Do you know the credit card policy of a Kazachstanian credit card company? If I know that the credit care company concerned has an end-of-month policy, then as an expiry date for 2019/03 I could use the first second that it is expired, so for the 2019/03 this would mean a value of `2019/04/01 00:00:00`. If the card expires at the beginning of the month, the expiration value for 2019/03 would be `2019/03/01 00:00:00`. Much more precise than 2019/03

Comment: Well there has been a lot of contributions on this but I just wanted a way to  warn my clients their card was about to expire a month before -  and that is it so if it will expire in march I will alert them  by end of February.  I have  fixed this and everything is working allright